# TST10 like prorgram using SSH

Tags: ssh, scripting

From time to time I have to login and issue the same commands to many different devices. I used to use telnet with TST10, at and old job, that was great and easy to use. But with security concerns at a new job we can only use SSH connections. I have and am currently using a batch file that runs through a CSV file of ip address that calls Putty and windows scripting to SSH to devices and issue the commands.

Some draw backs are that doing so requires putty to be the active window rendering the computer useless until all the ip addresses and commands have been gone through. Also getting the timing right for connecting to a device and then issuing commands is very tedious. and lastly if the computer locks the screen or you close the RDP session the script fails.

With TST10 it automatically waited until a particular prompt like > or # appeared then issued the next command. It also did not have to be the active window nor did it matter if the screen was locked or the RDP session closed. Is there any program out there like TST10 that does SSH sessions as well?